# If statement using an environment variable

Tags: apache2

In my apache configuration, I am trying to only activate a snippet of code if an environment variable is set to true.

So I have something like this:

```
<If "'${MY_ENV_VAR}' == 'true'">
  # do something
</If>
```

For some reason, this is not currently working, does anybody have any idea what might be wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: Where is the variable set? Using `SetEnv`, or in the calling shell? If so, do you use PassEnv?

Comment: It is set in the shell

Comment: Do you [use the passenv directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html)? Please post more of your configuration.

Comment: no there is not much more in my config, I have this environment variable in the shell, so that if I type "env" in the shell, I see MY_ENV_VAR=true. I'd like to use this var to enable or disable a section in apache but can't find exactly how. (thanks for your time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not working because you're not telling apache to pass the environment variables using the PassEnv directive.

You need mod_env loaded, and you have to include a stanza such as

```
PassEnv MY_ENV_VAR
```

It's fairly well documented in [the Apache Manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html)